# sphinx reset one filter only

Tags: php, filter, sphinx, reset

I have sphinx object. I got all the result from sphinx. Now I need to run the search again with out resetting the complete object. I just need to reset a single filter .

This is my filter I need to reset 
$sphinx->SetFilter("cid", $category_ids);

How can I reset one filter only. I need old values to be removed completely from filter.

Comment: $sphinx->ResetFilters(); doesn't work for you?

Comment: Got no function for this so modified sphinx object

foreach ($sb_sphinx->_filters as $key=>$filter)
{    
     if($filter['attr'] == sb_cid)
     {
 unset($sb_sphinx->_filters[$key]);
     }
}

Comment: You should post your comment as a Answer. You can then accept the answer (even your own) so that the question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your SphinxClient class

```
<?php
   function RemoveFilter ( $attribute )
   {
      assert ( is_string($attribute) );

      foreach($this->_filters AS $key => $filter){
         if($filter['attr'] == $attribute){
            unset($this->_filters[$key]);
            break;
         }
      }
   }
?>
```

Then run `$SphinxClient->RemoveFilter('your filter');` to remove the filter.

Comment: Hi, I install sphinx via pecl. And use on php $sphinx = new Sphinx(); to where should i add this function ?